# variants, existential polymorphism in c++

Tags: c++, types, polymorphism, variant, subtype

I am conducting a research on type systems. For this work I am investigating the usages of Variants, structural subtyping, universal polymorphism and existential polymorphism in popular languages. Functional languages like heskell, ocaml provides such functionaries. But I want to whether a popular language like C++ provide above functionality. That means how C++ implemented

1. variants
2. structural subtyping
3. universal polymorphism
4. existential polymorphism.

Comment: For variants you can have a look at boost.variant, the rest I have no idea what that may be (which probably means you can do it with variadic templates).

Comment: hi does variants can be implemented by struct and unions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unions can be viewed as a rudimentary form of variant, but in reality, they are more a primitive mechanism for overlaying memory (and unsafe).
2. There is no structural typing, let alone subtyping, in C++. All types are nominal.
3. Templates have some superficial similarity to universal polymorphism, but are actually quite different. In essence, they are glorified macros with little to no type checking (like with macros, both checking and code generation happens after expansion).
4. There is no form of existential types in C++ (there is a limited form in Java, namely wildcards).

Some of these features can be simulated to some extent using subtyping, but that remains far less expressive (or convenient).

Comment: You can kind of emulate existential types via incomplete class-types (best example being the pimpl idiom), but that's pushing it.

Comment: `boost::variant` is a very nice implementation of variants. The Concepts proposal implements structural subtyping, no? Also, I don't know much about the phylogeny of type semantics… but doesn't the template specialization partial ordering count as strict type checking a la universal polymorphism? This is an important tool for dispatching over type structures in metaprograms.

Comment: hi i am researching on basic programming language features, thats why i think boost::variant cannot be a good point. btw, does runtime polymorphism kind of structural typing? @Andreas Rossberg

Comment: @Potatoswatter: concepts would have given something similar to (bounded) universal quantification, but they never made it and it's all a bit too messy to really say (and so is their relation to structural types). Dispatching over types is rather unrelated to parametric polymorphism btw (in fact, it destroys the "parametric" in it) - in type theory terms it is more akin to intensional type analysis.

Comment: @Pbasak: there is no such thing as "runtime polymorphism" as far as type theory is concerned - that is merely confused terminology that is (unfortunately) wide-spread in OO circles ;). In any case, I don't see what it has to do with structural types.